Not able to use {{HYPERLINK:FieldName:DisplayText}} for my conga merge field
I have a conga query. I want to use a conga merge field fetched from that conga query and display it as a clickable link in my conga template. The conga merge field (URL field in salesforce) that i want to display as a clickable link is
{{TableStart:OLIAssetFields}}
{{OPPORTUNITYLINEITEMEDITION_PART_OF_SERIES_T_C_URL}}
{{TableEnd:OLIAssetFields}}

Can anyone please help me how to use this conga provided syntax {{HYPERLINK:FieldName:DisplayText}} for my field?

You need to contact Conga support.
